# Frequency synchronization in OFDM

Tags: digital-communications, ofdm

Could you please help me understanding how the null sub-carriers can be used to estimate the carrier frequency offset and thus performing frequency Synchronization at the receiver?

Answer (score 0):

That depends, but usually rough frequency correction in an OFDM receiver is done by simply looking at which carriers have significant energy, which don't; you can do that, for example, by comparing the sum of all non-null carriers' energies to that of all null-carrier energies, and shifting that around until the ratio maximizes. Pretty simple idea!

Comment: " you can do that, for example, by comparing the sum of all non-null carriers' energies to that of all null-carrier energies ", could you clearify this section please?

Comment: You take the energy of samples from the null carriers. You add them up.